# How to automatically parse out the fields(Protobuf) used in the code?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

Given the following `trade.proto` file:

```
message Trade {
    message ProductInfo {
      optional uint64 product_id = 1;
      optional String product_name = 2;
      repeated int other_field = 3;
    }
    optional string id = 1;
    optional uint64 partition_time = 2;
    optional ProductInfo product_info= 3;
}
```

Given the following code：

```
def getOtherFieldSize(trade: Trade): Int = {
  if (20221205 == trade.getPartitionTime) {
    trade.getProductInfo.getOtherFieldList.size
  } else {
    0
  }
}
```

How to get the fields of `trade.proto` used in the code? For example:

```
partition_time
product_info.other_field
```

Comment: Can you explain (or give example of) how you intend to use these "other fields"? For type safety it is best to refer to fields explicitly if possible.

Comment: @Tim Currently `trade.proto` contains thousands of fields, I hope to automatically get which fields are in use.

Comment: Although you can, in principle, use Scala runtime reflection (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html), the easy by which you can use reflection depends in a large part of the code generated by your specific Scala proto code generator.  So, please, add which code generator has been used. That provides contributors the opportunity to answer your question more specifically.

Comment: I would start by looking at why your `proto` has a `message` with thousands of fields; that really isn't the way to "structure" data.

Comment: @nanitous Using runtime reflection can be now tricky. It's not clear for arbitrary piece of code what fields to reflect.

Comment: @Birkety Suppose all classes auto-generated by Protobuf are in some package. You can define an advice with joint point "after returning" "execution" for all `getX` methods in the package. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html